# for loop doesnt read my if statement

Tags: c, for-loop

Im trying to turn on an LED via a light sensor. But everytime I try to run it the light sensor works but it wont go past the line "printf(Voltage..). it doesnt reach the if loop. why is that? I added the printf in each if statement so i know i could reach that line.

```
int doADCConversion()
{
ADC0->SC1[0] = ADC_SC1_ADCH(19);


while ((ADC0->SC1[0] & ADC_SC1_COCO_MASK) == 0)
{
    printf("Conversion in progress..\n");
}


return ADC0->R[0];
 }


    for(;;)
    {
    temp = doADCConversion();
    printf("Voltage = %d\n", temp);

    if(temp < 50){
        printf("Turn on LED 1/n");
        setLED(0);
        delay();
    }
    else if (temp < 100){
        printf("Turn on LED 2/n");
        setLED(1);
        delay();
    }
    else if (temp < 150){
        printf("Turn on LED 3/n");
        setLED(2);
        delay();
    }
    else if (temp < 200){
        printf("Turn on LED 4/n");
        setLED(3);
        delay();
    }
    else if (temp < 250){
        printf("Turn on LED 5/n");
        setLED(4);
        delay();
    }
    else {
        setLED(5);
        printf("Turn on LED 6/n");
        delay();
    }
 }
```

Comment: FWIW, there is nothing called `if` loop. It's a conditional statement.

Comment: What do you think `return` *does*?

Comment: @EOF Maybe, the `for` loop is in another snippet. Notice the indent...

Comment: Formatting your code properly would be a big help both for yourself and for your readers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The indentation doesn't matter. The closing curly brace *does*, but either way the code makes no sense.

Comment: Try to replace /n by \n in each of your printf statement.

Comment: Do you see lots of "Voltage..." lines?

Comment: Can anyone explain me these undeserved downvotes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The downvotes are not undeserved. The code, as posted, makes no sense, since the `for`-loop is not part of the function.

Comment: @EOF: I know that this isn't a valid program, but I found all necessary information to understand the question and I appreciate it is not cluttered with unnecessary code. I assume your explanation is the right one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You found enough information to wildly speculate about the reason for the program's behavior. I'm not at all convinced your answer is is any way useful.

Comment: @EOF: We are told that `printf("Voltage...` is executed, but not the subsequent `printf` in the if cascade. The snippet is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that as you terminated the strings with `"/n"` instead of a newline `"\n"`, the `printf` output remains buffered.

Comment: There will be a '\n' after "Voltage..." in the next loop.

Comment: Maybe delay() is delaying too much :)

Comment: @Vincent: Or performing `unprintf` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify it

```
#define min(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)

while (1) {
    temp = doADCConversion();
    printf("Voltage = %d\n", temp);
    temp = min(5, temp / 50);
    printf("Turn on LED %d\n", temp + 1);    // newline is `\n`
    setLED(temp);
    delay();
}
```

**NOTE**: Escape sequences go with backslash (`\`).

Answer (score 0):

Put your for section in main loop or in a function.
Else it gets optimized because it is never been used, though it is valid C.

Also it would be good to use identing, so it is easier to see.

Comment: `printf("Voltage...` is executed.